# Windows 8 appbar on selected item (like startup screen)

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, appbar

What I want to achieve in my application is the same as what windows did on their start up screen. When you select an item, open the appbar and show more items. When you just open te appbar when not selecting anything, don't show those items.

So far so good and it works like I want it to be. But there is some issue I can't solve. When you select an item on the start up screen, you can't close te appbar when right clicking anywhere on the screen. You have to deselect the item.

I just can't figure out how to disable that right click to close the appbar. Because then I am in a state where I have a selected item, but no appbar. I don't want that...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can the user select only one item or multiple items in your scenario?

Answer (score 1):

There is a property called [IsSticky](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar.issticky.aspx)

this can be used to stop you appbar from collapsing.

the other option you have is to hooking into [Closed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar.closed.aspx) event and force it to re-open.

Based on the screen you provided aka the Metro UI :) i'd say that create a page that just hosts other tiles. 
I have done a similar thing in one of my apps, have a look at 
http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-gb/app/cineworld/7adfde16-33c3-4b51-b758-00366325288d

Have a look at [Coding4Fun](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) or [Callisto](https://github.com/timheuer/Callisto)

Comment: That doesn't work entirely as I want it to be. When the user right clicks his mouse button, the appbar will dissapear. IsSticky only makes sure that the appbar will not close when the user presses the left mouse button.

Comment: another option is to use closed event and reopen. no other options. not using appbar at least

Comment: Any idea on how windows implemented it in the startupscreen? I'm willing to use another component if that works better in my use case...

Comment: I have no idea what you are referring to..  startup screen ? a screenshot of what you mean might actually help me.. in a very slow state today :|

Comment: Here is a [screenshot](http://i.i.com.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim/2012/08/20/win8-start-screen.png) of the startup screen where I'm referring to.
If you press a tile with the right mouse button, the appbar will appear and it is not possible to remove the appbar untill you deselect the tile.

Answer (score 1):

Set the AppBar property **IsSticky="true"** and handle the event **RightTapped** on your GridView/ListView, and in the event handler set **e.Handled = true;**
This will stop the rightclick/swipe routed event from reaching Page and it won't close the AppBar.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `hide()` function of the appbar and replace it with something like this:

```
appBar.hide = function () {
        /// <signature helpKeyword="WinJS.UI.AppBar.hide">
        /// <summary locid="WinJS.UI.AppBar.hide">
        /// Hides the AppBar, if visible, regardless of other state
        /// </summary>
        /// </signature>
        // Just wrap the private one
        var listView = document.getElementById("yourListView").winControl;
        var count = listView.selection.count();

        if(count <1)
            this._hide();
}
```

It's not a great workaround, but it works like a charm :)